# Using Expression Engine modules in Core + multisite

Tags: core

Is it possible to use some of the modules from the regular version of EE in the EE Core? Also, outside of the multi-site manager for EE, is there any other way to run multiple sites of of the regular version of EE?

Comment: This is a really broad question. Perhaps you could include some examples of specific modules you were thinking about. Also It might be helpful to read through some of the documentation provided by ellis labs. https://store.ellislab.com/#ee-core

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here:

1) Is it possible to use some of the modules from the regular version of EE in the EE Core?

No. That would be a violation of the license agreement. You can use any 3rd party add-ons you like, as long as they work with Core, which means they cannot rely on any of the modules not included in Core. However, copying the modules over from the commercial version to a Core installation would be equivalent to stealing the software.

2) Outside of the multi-site manager for EE, is there any other way to run multiple sites of of the regular version of EE?

There are ways to do it, involving modifying your .htaccess, but again it violates the license agreement, as the license grants use for a single site.

If you have special case scenarios, you may want to run them by EllisLab via email, as they are the experts and final say on their license agreement.